# How does stretch processing work for SFCW?

Tags: signal-processing, dsp, radar, dds

I've been reading about FMCW radar, and I understand that a chirped signal can be de-chirped by mixing it with a copy of itself, which yields a beat frequency which is much easier to process and is proportional to the time delay between the transmitted and received signals. However, a lot of the implementations that I've seen have used a frequency ramp with discrete frequency steps, presumably because it is much easier to implement.

Initially I assumed that stretch processing would not work with a SFCW radar, since the discrete frequency steps would create two beat frequencies instead of one when the frequency steps didn't line up (I made [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zgflpwn4md) model for myself). But after doing more research on how one would actually create a continuous, wideband chirp, I could only find the VCO based solution in the MIT coffee can radar (which is only as linear as the VCO) and [this](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/8780/gomezgarciaalvestegui_ku_0099m_11930_data_1.pdf?sequence=1) implementation, which uses a DDS IC with discrete frequency steps as a reference. I'm certain that I must be missing something.

Is stretch processing possible with SFCW chirps? If so, does it come at a cost of decreased range resolution? Why or why not? If it isn't possible, how are wideband continuous chirps actually generated?

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user201537 I wrote an answer that describes how the de-chirping process looks like mathematically and provides an example: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68234/generating-if-signal-for-fmcw-radar/68368#68368

Here I briefly mention how stepped-FM waveforms work: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68712/fmcw-radar-using-fsk-superimposed-lfm-ramp/68971#68971

The basic answer is that stepped-FM waveforms are actually more complex to implement that just a straight up LFM waveform when trying to achieve similar range resolutions.

Comment: Are we talking about hardware or software? A DDS is hardware, so is a VCO

Comment: @Envidia that is very helpful, thank you